# Computed column formula for row_number function

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, calculated-columns, sql-view

I am trying to find a formula for a computed column that will return same results as the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. since I cannot use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and save results on the table.
I have a table as below;

```
ID  YEAR  
1   2018      
2   2018      
3   2019      
4   2019      
5   2020      
6   2018      
7   2019
```

I would like a formulae that will compute and assign numbers the rows depending with year as shown below;

```
ID     YEAR     COMPUTED COLUMN
1      2018     1
2      2018     2  
3      2019     1  
4      2019     2  
5      2020     1  
6      2018     3  
7      2019     3
```

Comment: Why cannot you not use row number?

Comment: Are you definitely looking for a computed column? i.e. a column defined in your table definition? Or do you just need a calculated column for your query?

Comment: row_number function cannot be used in a table and I want the results to save in a column on my table

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to find a formula for a computed column that will return same results as the ROW_NUMBER() function.

You just can't use window functions in a computed column; window functions operate on a range of rows (called the *window frame*), while a computed column has visibility to the row it belongs to only.

> I cannot use the ROW_NUMBER() function and save results on the table

While this is technically possible, I would not recommend it. This is derived information, that can be computed on the fly whenever needed. You could use a view instead:

```
create view myview
as
select
    id, 
    year,
    row_number() over (partition by year order by id) rn
from mytable
```

Comment: I have already created the view but I realized I can't use data from a view in my application

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way around it.

It's not a good way though...

```
select
    id, 
    year,
    row_number() over(partition by year order by id) rn,
    (select count(*) from Table1 t where t.YEAR=d.YEAR and t.ID<=d.ID) PoorRN
from Table1 d
order by id
```

• This is going to have a very bad performance.
If your table has over a million rows - just go ahead and through it on production and tell us what happened ;)

Answer (score -1):

Update: Based on the comments by OP, I have a new suggestion -

1. From the original table - create a view and then give numbers to each year

   create view original_table_view
   as
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by [year] order by ID) as numbering
   from original_table
2. Create a new table and apply a Merge on the new table from view

   create table New_table (id int, [year] int, numbering int)

Create Merge syntax -

```
merge new_table t using original_table_view v
on (t.id = v.id) --merge_condition 
when matched then update set 
t.[year]=v.[year],
t.numbering=v.numbering
when not matched by target
then insert ( id, [year], numbering)
values (v.id, v.[year],numbering)
when not matched by source
then delete;
```

SO now if in future, if new values are inserted in the original table, you just need to run the merge query to update the new table.

view data -

```
select * from original_table order by ID
select * from original_table_view order by ID
select * from New_table order by ID
```

Old Answer:
I confused your query with calculated column instead of the computed column (sorry about that)

You cannot store function as a computed column in the SQL server. However, you can create a view on the table and then call the same.

example -

create table as below

```
create table year_computed2 (ID int, Year int )
go

insert into year_computed2 values (1,2018 )
insert into year_computed2 values (2,2018 )
insert into year_computed2 values (3,2019 )
insert into year_computed2 values (4,2019 )
insert into year_computed2 values (5,2020 )
insert into year_computed2 values (6,2018 )
insert into year_computed2 values (7,2019 )
go
```

Now Create a view using Row_number() function (you can also use Rank() and Ntile())

```
alter view year_computed_view as
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by [year] order by ID) as Rn from year_computed2
```

Now Query this view like below

```
select * from year_computed_view order by ID
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHCQJ.jpg)

---

> In-case you were talking about the calculated column - below answer is
> available

---

`Dense_Rank()`

```
select DISTINCT id, [year], DENSE_RANK() over ( order by [year]) as [Dense_rank]
from year_computed
ORDER BY ID
```

Output is like:

[image]

If Dense_rank does't fulfill then try below two functions -

1. Rank()

   select DISTINCT id, [year], RANK() over ( partition by [year] order by ID) as [Rank]
   from year_computed
   ORDER BY ID

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8h5F.jpg)

2. NTile()

   declare @ntile_count int = (select count (distinct [year])from year_computed)
   select  id, [year], ntile(@ntile_count) over (partition by [year] order by id)  as rn from year_computed ORDER BY ID

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqjZf.jpg)

Comment: select  id, [year], rank() over (partition by [year] order by id)  as rn from year_computed ORDER BY ID

rank() also gives exact same result as the table you shared. If rank() is also not allowed then might as well add these functions in question too

Comment: alternatively

declare @ntile_count int = (select count (distinct [year])from year_computed)
select  id, [year], ntile(@ntile_count) over (partition by [year] order by id)  as rn from year_computed ORDER BY ID


use this

Comment: Its okay, just trying to help. in-fact creating a view is pointless too since you aren't using computed column anyways. therefore my bottom two suggestions are still valid. :-)

Comment: getting the ROW_NUMBER results is not a problem, I can do it with a query or a viev, the issue is moving those results to a table

Comment: But if you create a new table and insert all values from the view, it should work. Its just that there will be no computed column in your table.